# forward packing not working in template class

Tags: c++, templates

I got a class uses template parameter pack:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(Ts &&...ts) {
    // do something 
  }
};
```

then use it:

```
std::string s;
Foo<std::string> foo(s);
```

But this code failed to compile, the compiler seems accept r-values, not "universe references":

```
note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> &&' for 1st argument
```

If I change to:

```
Foo<std::string> foo(std::move(s));
```

then it works.

but if I test with a template function:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
void Bar(Ts &&... ts) {
  // do something
}
```

and then use it:

```
Bar(s);
```

it works fine. So what do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) must be function parameters of **function templates**,

> 1) function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue reference to cv-unqualified type template parameter of that same function template:

`Foo::Foo` is a non-template constructor, then `ts` is just declared as rvalue-reference.

You might want

```
template<typename ...Ts>
class Foo {
 public:
  template<typename ...Tf>
  Foo(Tf &&...ts) {
    // do something 
  }
};
```

Or you can make two overloaded constructors which taking lvalue-reference and rvalue-reference.

Comment: Then any way I can do except to make the constructor a template function?

Comment: @ravenisadesk AFAIK, no for forwarding reference; you might make two constructors taking lvalue-reference and rvalue-reference.

Comment: Sounds acceptable.